# How do I get the SHA1 checksum of an image react native

Tags: react-native, expo, checksum, imagepicker, backblaze

I have been at this for hours now. I need to get the SHA1 checksum of an image in Expo React Native. I am using the [ImagePicker API](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/) to get the image and can see that I can get the MD5 hash of the image which I verified but they are not the same thing according to google

> Whereas MD5 produces a 128-bit hash, SHA1 generates 160-bit hash (20
> bytes).

I specifically need to get this. This is because I am trying to upload to [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com) B2 through their [API](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_upload_file.html).

I was told this is a required field in order to check the file arrived correctly. I tried using the [expo-crypto](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/crypto/) module but it only hashes strings.

Please is there any library or something I could use to do this?

Here's my trial:

Launch the image picker

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1.91, 1],
      exif:true,
      base64:true,
      quality: 1,
    });
```

Get the result. returns:

```
Object {
  "cancelled": false,
  "exif": Object {
    "ImageLength": 1080,
    "ImageWidth": 1080,
    "LightSource": 0,
    "Orientation": 0,
  },
  "height": 1080,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.blipmoore.blipmoore_cleaner/cache/ImagePicker/c8ac399d-ae12-40f6-95c6-994ddf99b5ed.jpg",
  "width": 1080,
}
```

Note for the above. I had to remove the base64 because it was too long.

I then try to use buffer to change the format of the base64,

```
Buffer.from(result.base64, '')
```

But there is no SHA-1 format. I do not even know if this is the correct thing to do.

On [this page](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/uploading.html) in the documentation, they said:

> You must always include the X-Bz-Content-Sha1 header with your upload
> request. The value you provide can be: (1) the 40-character hex
> checksum of the file, (2) the string hex_digits_at_end, or (3) the
> string do_not_verify.

I cannot opt for 3 for obvious reasons. Please what do I do? I can get a buffer hex value from my code but I cannot verify it's the right thing because on the docs it says, a `40-character hex checksum` and the hex value I get from the buffer is like a 1000+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is a way of creating a fixed length 'digest' from variable-length input, such as an image you want to upload. Although SHA-1 is no longer considered secure in a cryptographic sense, it can still be used as a checksum that the data that a service such as Backblaze B2 received is the same as the data that you sent.

Looking at Expo's [Crypto.digestStringAsync()](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/#cryptodigeststringasyncalgorithm-data-options) function, you are correct - it only works with strings.

Fortunately, there are pure JavaScript implementations of SHA-1 out there - I was able to use [Rusha](https://github.com/srijs/rusha) to do the job. Here's my code; you can also try it out in [this Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@metadaddy/create-a-sha-1-digest-of-an-image).

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "rusha": "~0.8.14",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.1.1",
    "buffer": "~6.0.3"
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
import Rusha from 'rusha';

export default function ImagePickerExample() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // Get an image from the user's device
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({ 
      allowsEditing: true, 
      aspect: [1.91, 1], 
      exif:true, 
      base64:true, 
      quality: 1, 
    });

    // Convert the image data from Base64 to binary
    const binaryImage = Buffer.from(result.base64, "base64");

    // Get the SHA-1 digest of the binary image data
    const digest = Rusha.createHash().update(binaryImage).digest('hex'); 
    console.log("SHA-1:", digest);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it a must to convert the image data from base64 to binary?

Comment: Yes. Base64 is just a way to convert binary data from its original form to an ASCII representation and back again. SHA-1 operates on the binary data, so you absolutely need to convert it.

Comment: Note that you'll also need to upload that binary data to B2 to store the image, rather than the base64 encoding.

Comment: You mean I upload the result I get from `binaryImage`? If yes I have done so but I do not get the correct file. I get something else stored in my storage with the file type application/octet-stream. I store the name as the name of the user but I do not know if I must store it as the file type name instead of the name of the user

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked. I just needed to save it as the correct file name to finish it up

Comment: You're welcome... BTW - you can pull the correct `Content-Type` from the URI that Expo gives you like this: `const contentType = result.uri.split(/[:;]/)[1]`

Comment: But it sounds like giving it the right filename allows B2 to guess the content type :-)

Comment: Yes. B2 automatically knows the right content type through the file name. Thanks again